# php include breaking

Tags: php

I have a php page that generates all the html and echo's it. Now I want to write a php script that I can use include to handle the footer code. that way if I need to update the footer on all the pages I can just edit the code in the included page.

But when I use include("footer.php"); and the footer page contains the footer code that works if it exists on the page it breaks and prints the code. Im very confused as too why?

```
  if(isset($_SESSION['user_cart']) && count($_SESSION['user_cart']) > 0)
```

Starts writing the code on the page if I include from  0)

Please help?

EDIT: The code in the footer is wrapped in `<?php   ?>`

Comment: include ALL of the code, not some snippet.

Comment: Does "footer.php" begin with "<?php"?

Comment: Please show your include statement as well as a few relevant lines of context. Please also include a sample of the output along with any error or warning messages you see on-screen or in the log files.

Comment: could you add the code where you call the footer, and the content of the footer, it's not too clear from your question

Answer (score 3):

You need to wrap that code in footer.php with php tags.

```
<?php

 if(isset($_SESSION['user_cart']) && count($_SESSION['user_cart']) > 0) ...

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Dont your short hand notation of php tags `<? ?>`, use `<?php ?>`instead...

Answer (score 1):

It sound like you didn't start php file with

```
<?php
```

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that your footer file has `<?php` in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you stated your question very clearly.

If you are echoing code out it will appear as soon as you include the file. Your file should look like this:

```
<?php require_once 'header.php';
// content goes here
require_once 'footer.php'; ?>
```